# How to get all the values from a Groovy Map in a select of a GSP page

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

Let's say we have a map like:

```
def mostBeautifulCities =
[
    cadiz : "Cádiz",
    KeyForCity2 : "some value for city2"
]
```

**How could we list all values?** (I did not find a easy way looking at the [Groovy JDK documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html)).

I want to show all values in a select control:

```
<g:select id="city" name="city" 
    from="${  mostBeautifulCities.(...)  }" 
    noSelection="${['':'Select a ugly city...']}" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<g:select  from="${mostBeautifulCities.entrySet()}" name="city"  optionKey="key" optionValue="value" ></g:select>
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why `optionKey="key"` is for. The select looks similar either with it or without it.

Comment: optionKey is what gets put in for value="" of the select element.  From a map, you want the key to be that value.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks one more time :)